# Filtrer with Entity field query builder

Tags: php, symfony

On Symfony 2.3 with JordiLlonchCrudGeneratorBundle :

I have an entity Activite which contains a ManyToOne relation with another entity Client (JoinColumn(nullable=false))

I have generated the CRUD with JordiLlonchCrudGeneratorBundle and it works fine.

Only, when I display the activité list, I want to have the possibility to filter by client.

So I have created a function in ClientRepository.php :

```
public function findActifClients()
  {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
   
    $qb->where('a.actif = :actif')
      ->setParameter('actif', true)
      ->orderBy('a.nom', 'ASC');
  
    return $qb;
  }
```

Then I have modified the ActiviteFilterType.php in this way :

```
class ActiviteFilterType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $myclients = array(
                    "1" => "Client01", 
                    "4" => "Client02", 
            );

    $builder
        //->add('id', 'filter_number_range')
        ->add('nom', 'filter_text')
        ->add('client', 'entity', array(
              'class' => 'Too\ClientBundle\Entity\Client',
              'property' => 'nom',
              'required' => false,
              'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->findActifClients();
              }
        ))
...
```

Now when I display the activite list I have the possibiloity to filter by client but the problem is that when I filter on one client the liste remains the same as if I had not filtered the list.

Could anybody help me on this ?

EDIT :
I continue to look for a solution - without success.

There's something weired :

Here is a version that works but here I put in the client array in a static way and this is not a real solution :

ActiviteFilterType.php :

```
class ActiviteFilterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $myclients = array(
                        "1" => "Client01",
                        "4" => "Client02",
                );
     
        $builder
            ->add('nom', 'filter_text')
 
            ->add('client', 'filter_choice', array(
                'choices' => $myclients,
            ))
```

...

As I said this version works : I can choose in the active client list and when clicking on "Filter" I get the list of activite that are related to that client.

I had a look on the HTML generated : its strictly the same HTML code in the form as in the first version (dynamic) :

```
<div>
    <label for="too_clientbundle_activitefiltertype_client">Client</label>
    <select id="too_clientbundle_activitefiltertype_client" name="too_clientbundle_activitefiltertype[client]">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Client01</option>
        <option value="4">Client02</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Really nobody with any idea what's going on ?

Comment: In this example you don't filter on 'nom', so it's correct that the results are the same. You should pass the value 'nom' to the repository method and add an `addWhere` which filters on 'nom'

Comment: I don't understand but perhaps its my explanation ? The add('nom', 'filter_text') is there to see if filtering is working and it is ! My problem is on : ->add('client', 'entity', ...

Answer (score 0):

You are simply not filtering by client at all on your first method.
This should give you an idea

```
public function findActifClients($clients)
  {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');

    $qb->where('a.actif = :actif AND a.id IN :clients')
      ->setParameter('actif', true)
      ->setParameter('clients', $clients)
      ->orderBy('a.nom', 'ASC');

    return $qb;
  }
```

And

```
class ActiviteFilterType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $clients = array(
                    "1", 
                    "4", 
            );

    $builder
        //->add('id', 'filter_number_range')
        ->add('nom', 'filter_text')
        ->add('client', 'entity', array(
              'class' => 'Too\ClientBundle\Entity\Client',
              'property' => 'nom',
              'required' => false,
              'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use($clients) {
                return $er->findActifClients($clients);
              }
        ))
```

Then if you want something dynamic you'll just have to pass your $clients array from your controller to the form builder.

Comment: Ok - even if I don't get it (sorry) it seems to be so : I'm not filtering bye client. But then even if I do not understand I tried the codee you are proposing and the result is still the same : no filtering on the client selected. If I can't get it this way - could you please give me a hint for the idea to pass $clients array from the controller to the form builder - because yes I need it dynamic !

Answer (score 0):

As I can't get it work with add entity, I tried to pass information form the controler to the form builder - works fine - I read that this could be considerated as dirty but as I can't find any other solution it will be this ...